# Arrow Function inside alert box triggering on 'onsubmit' button of a form

Tags: javascript, html

my this code outputs the function as it is but I want it to return the value of 'p8' id and I want to use arrow function.

```
<form onsubmit="alert(()=>{document.getElementById('p8').value})">
    <label>PAlindrome</label>
    <input type="text" id="p8"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Please be more descriptive.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: top line was not visible before the edit

Comment: Can you confirm that what you want is to alert the value of the p8 input when the form is submitted?

Comment: yes, right now I just want to print the alert value, but after that I want to check the input value with some constant string and output the result as true or false.

Comment: The only problem is that I want all of that to be written in a line using arrow function. I don't want to write the function somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *call* the function. It's done by adding `()` to the `(function)`.

```html
<form onsubmit="alert((()=>{document.getElementById('p8').value})())">
  <label>PAlindrome</label>
  <input type="text" id="p8"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or easier:

```
<form onsubmit="alert(document.getElementById('p8').value)">
  <label>PAlindrome</label>
  <input type="text" id="p8"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```